# javascript-state-machine onafterevent isn't being called

Tags: javascript, user-interface, workflow

I'm using the so far excellent ['javascript-state-machine'](https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine) library. However, with my events that look like A), I have a few transition callbacks that look like B). I have a similar 'onafterevent' callback that is working elsewhere. But **'onafterEEpart'** isn't firing and I can't figure out why.

I'm i) calling **'my-state-machine.EEpart'**, which should fire the callbacks throughout the transition. And ii) **'onbeforeEEpart'** is getting called. So I'm at a loss as to why this onafterevent isn't getting called.

Anyone seen anything like this before? Thanks in advance.

A)

```
    esm : StateMachine.create({
                               initial:  'Es',
                               events: [
                                 { name: 'EsE', from: 'Es', to: 'E' }, 
                                 { name: 'EEpart', from: 'E', to: 'Epart' },     
                                 { name: 'EpartE', from: 'Epart', to: 'E' },
                                 { name: 'EEs', from: 'E', to: 'Es' }
                               ]
```

B)

```
    onbeforeEEpart: (event, from, to, args) ->
    ... 

    onafterEEpart: (event, from, to, args) -> 
    ...
```

**UPDATE [03/23/2012; 2:49am]**

I tried to manually transition from Epart->E, and got the error in A). It seems the transition from E->Epart never completed. And I have a theory as to why.

After the previous transition, I had to attach the next transition to a click function, as seen in B). Doing that included using underscore to rebind my transition function to my state machine. I think this is causing the error. And if it is, is there a correct way to pass transition functions around to be fired?

Thanks

**A)**

```
    Uncaught event EpartE inappropriate because previous transition did not complete
```

**B)**

```
    onafterPreviousEvent: (event, from, to, args) ->
      console.log('END Transition from Es->E')

      $(my-element)
        .bind('click',
              { fu: bar }, 
              _.bind(args.data.esm.EEpart, args.data.esm))   # state machine is 'args.data.esm'
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I solved this one. It turns out I had an **onleaveE** event function that was returning a StateMachine.ASYNC flag. The callback workflow is below, and **onleaveE** was being called and returning an ASYNC flag before **onafterEEpart** could be called:

- onbeforeevent - fired before the event
- onleavestate - fired when leaving the old state
- onenterstate - fired when entering the new state
- onafterevent - fired after the event

Typically, when you return a StateMachine.ASTNC flag, you have to manually call **transition()** on your stateMachine object. This is tricky, and had me for a day or so. Hopefully it helps someone out in future.